# Write csv columwise

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I have a list of lists example:
list_of_lists = [['name1', 'number1', 'comment1'], ['name2', 'number2', 'comment2'], ['name3', 'number3', 'comment3']]

I want to write them into a csv file that should look like this:

```
NAME  NUMBER  COMMENT
name1 number1 comment1
name2 number2 comment2
name3 number3 comment3
```

I tried:

```
rows = zip(*list_of_lists)
import csv
with open('new.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But that writes it as:

```
name1    name2   name3
number1  number2 comment2
comment1 number3 comment3
```

If I use `rows = zip(list_of_lists)` instead of `rows = zip(*list_of_lists)`, I get all data as string in csv:

```
"name1, number1, comment1"
"name2, number2, comment2"
"name3, number3, comment3"
```

How do I get the desired result?

Comment: Why do you want to use `zip()` at all ? Your data are already in the right format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use them directly.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

list_of_lists = [['name1', 'number1', 'comment1'], ['name2', 'number2', 'comment2'], ['name3', 'number3', 'comment3']]

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["NAME", "NUMBER", "COMMENT"])
    for row in list_of_lists:
        writer.writerow(row)
```